# Isolated DC/DC converter help

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I would really appreciate if someone would share his insights on whether an isolated DC/DC converter of a fixed output (12V) can sustain that output even when input is lower than 12V, the datasheet says the input range 9-36 VDC which may be the answer but i would really like to get a confirmation if possible.

Also a side question, this datasheet does not indicate any input or output filters or recommended capacitors for optimal operation except a 10F MLCC at the output , any recommendations on this ? my thought was to throw a few bulk capacitors at the input/output and call it a day.

[DC/DC Converter](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/RECOM-Power/RS12-2412SZ?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvGsmoEFRKS8Fb388U%2FtE5%252BVpzTODlol6ETH0V1MgtB6A%3D%3D)

[Datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/RS12-1760803.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *this datasheet does not indicate any input or output filters or
>   recommended capacitors for optimal operation except a 10F MLCC at the
>   output , any recommendations on this ?*

First of all read this section in the data sheet on how to make it compliant with EN55032: -

[image]

> *I would really appreciate if someone would share his insights on
>   whether an isolated DC/DC converter of a fixed output (12V) can
>   sustain that output even when input is lower than 12V, the datasheet
>   says the input range 9-36 VDC which may be the answer but i would
>   really like to get a confirmation if possible.*

Secondy, yes it will work from 9 volts input to 36 volts input because, internally, is a flyback converter.